# Evaluating $\iiint e^{-2r} \cos^2\theta \, dV $ over all space.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral $\iiint e^{-2r} \cos^2\theta \, dV $ over all space.

What I have done: I wrote the limit of integration as this: $\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty r^2e^{-2r} \cos^2\theta \sin\theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\phi $ Whenever The first integral is given, it is $1/4\cos^2\theta \sin\theta$ Then when I integrate with respect to the second integral, I end up with an answer that is $= 0$.

Comment: Are you sure about $\sin \theta$? It seems to me it should be $\sin \phi$.

Comment: Mathematicians and physicists seem to follow opposite conventions about which is $\theta$ and which is $\varphi$.  In this case one can tell by the bounds of integration that $\varphi$ is latitude and $\theta$ is longitude.  As longitude varies, symmetry shows there is no reason to multiply $d\theta$ by any non-constant function of $\theta$.  I wonder if you saw a book by a physicist who used the letter $\theta$ for latitude and it said $\sin\theta\,d\theta$.  If so, then, since you are using $\varphi$ rather than $\theta$ for latitude, you need $\sin\varphi\,d\varphi$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It is clear that the integral you start with should evaluate to a positive number and the one you've written down must be zero. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spherical coordinates then
\begin{align}
\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-2r}\cos^2 \theta \;dV&=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}r^2e^{-2r}\cos^2\theta\sin\phi\;dr d\theta d\phi\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\left(-\frac{1}{2}r^2-\frac{1}{2}r-\frac{1}{4}\right)e^{-2r}\right]_{0}^{\infty}\cos^2\theta\sin\phi\; d\theta d\phi\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left(0+\frac{1}{4}\right)\cos^2\theta\sin\phi\; d\theta d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos 2\theta}{2}\sin\phi\; d\theta d\phi
\end{align}
You can complete it from here.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2 S \sin S \, dS$  you cannot substitute $\cos S=T $ and $\sin S \, dS=-dT$ over the whole range of $S$ because $\cos$  is not one-to-one on $[0,2\pi]$. Split the integral with respect to $\theta$ into 2 integrals : $\theta \in [0.\pi]$ and $\theta \in [\pi,2\pi ]$.